# Force R to write scientific notations as n.nn x 10^-n with superscript

Tags: r, formatting, notation

Let's say I have two floats

```
a <- 8.9384920e-24
b <- 0.00293892837
```

I would like to display either of them in 10-base scientific notation rounded to two decimals on a graph, possibly using `paste()`, but with superscript formatting after the 10.

```
8.94 x 10^-24 #no ^ and superscript font
2.94 x 10^-4  #no ^ and supercript font, should be -4, not -04
```

This is really maniac but it has been requested by a superior, it has to be done in base R (not ggplot2) or I will have to re-write 600 lines of code... Right now all I can see is that floats are printed differently depending on how big they are...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may check `eaxis` in package `sfsmisc`

```
# some data
x <- seq(1, 100000, len = 10)
y <- seq(1e-5, 1e-4, len = 10)

# default axes
plot(x, y)
```

[image]

```
# eaxis
plot(x, y, axes = FALSE)
eaxis(side = 1)
eaxis(side = 2)
```

[image]

You may also create a label `expression` using `pretty10exp()` from the same package. For example to apply the format to a plot title:

```
plot(x, y, axes = FALSE)
title(pretty10exp(y[1]))
```

[image]

Comment: This is very nice although in the OP I intended to use it on one variable, not on the axes. But thanks to your reply I was able to check the `sfsmisc` package and found the function `pretty10exp()` which does exactly what I want! I took the liberty to edit your answer so that it includes `pretty10exp()` is that ok?