# Alternatives to paste( ) to concatenate formatted text expressions on a graph?

Tags: r, graph, output, scientific-notation

I'm using `pretty10exp()` from the `sfsmisc` package to make the scientific notation look better. For example:

```
library(sfsmisc)
a <- 0.000392884
```

The output of `pretty10exp()` looks like this:

```
> pretty10exp(a, digits.fuzz=3) #round to display a certain number of digits
expression(3.93 %*% 10^-4)
```

I can use this to display the pretty version of `a` on a graph's title or axes as described in this post:
[Force R to write scientific notations as n.nn x 10^-n with superscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833294/force-r-to-write-scientific-notations-as-n-nn-x-10-n-with-superscript/22833996#22833996)

However, things get ugly again when I try to combine it with `paste()` to write a sequence of character strings like this:

```
# some data
x <- seq(1, 100000, len = 10)
y <- seq(1e-5, 1e-4, len = 10)

# default plot
plot(x, y)
legend("topleft", bty="n",legend=paste("p =", pretty10exp(a, digits.fuzz=3)))
```

Which gives me the following graph, so I suppose `paste()` is not able to handle formatted expressions of the kind that can be found in the output of `pretty10exp()`:

[image]

Is there an alternative to `paste()` that I could use to combine the expressions "p =" and the scientific notation of `pretty10exp()`?

Comment: Yep.  One I know about is `bquote`.  You may be able to use `call`, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I just tried `bquote` but I'm not sure I'm using it right, the only thing that gets displayed is "p =" and nothing else...

Comment: maybe have a look at `sprintf`

Comment: Same for `sprintf` it just completely ignores everything after the "p =", is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I thought `bquote` would be used *instead of* `paste` but you actually put it inside the `paste` brackets, lemme try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is just to copy what `pretty10exp()` does, which for a single numeric, `a`, and the options you set/defaults, is essentially:

```
a <- 0.00039288
digits.fuzz <- 3
eT <- floor(log10(abs(a)) + 10^-digits.fuzz)
mT <- signif(a/10^eT, digits.fuzz)
SS <- substitute(p == A %*% 10^E, list(A = mT, E = eT))
plot(1:10)
legend("topleft", bty = "n", legend = SS)
```

The equivalent using `bquote()` would be

```
SS <- bquote(p == .(mT) %*% 10^.(eT))
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not a precise answer, but I just play around with things for a while.  `bquote` is nice once you get a feel for it.

```
> call("rep", 10, 7)
## rep(10, 7)

> bquote(.(call("rep", 10, 7)) * q^5)
## rep(10, 7) * q^5

> sprintf("paste('%smm'^'%s')", 5, 5)
## [1] "paste('5mm'^'5')"
```

And my personal favorite, which will of course return `TRUE`...
just as soon as I someone writes `is.awesome`.

```
> bquote( f <- function(x) { is.awesome(R) })
## f <- function(x) {
##     is.awesome(R)
## }
```