# linebreak and superscript in bquote axis label ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scientific-notation

After looking at many examples and lots of trying, I'm still failing to combine text strings and an expression into ggplot2 axis labels to exactly what I want.

what I am trying to get here is the x-axis label to be: 
[image: axis label]

the ingredients:

```
parname <- 'FL.Red.Total'
xmean <- 123.34
xsigma <- 2580.23
```

to change the numbers to 10^n notations I use this formula:

```
sci_form10 <- function(x) {
    paste(gsub("e\\+", " \xB7 10^", scientific_format()(x)))
}
```

the name would then be build by:

```
  labs( x = bquote(.(gsub('\\.', '\\ ', parname)) ~ " (a.u.) (" ~ mu ~ "=" ~ .(sci_form10(xmean)) ~ ", " ~ sigma ~ " =" ~ .(sci_form10(xsigma)) ~ ")" ))
```

**I'm hoping to replace `10^04`  with 10 followed by a 4 in superscript** and to add a linebreak to the labels as the first image shows

The test code:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(scales)
 sci_form10 <- function(x) {
        paste(gsub("e\\+", " * 10^", scientific_format()(x)))
 }

 parname <- 'FL.Red.Total'
 xmean <- 123.34
 xsigma <- 2580.23
 ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=cyl)) +
        geom_point() +  
        labs( x = bquote(.(gsub('\\.', '\\ ', parname)) ~ " (a.u.) (" ~ mu ~ "=" ~ .(sci_form10(xmean)) ~ ", " ~ sigma ~ " =" ~ .(sci_form10(xsigma)) ~ ")" ))
```

gives:

[image: best effort]

p.s. I also tried

```
sci_form10 <- function(x) {
        paste(gsub(".*e\\+", "10^", scientific_format()(x)))
  }
```

which only gives the 10^03 part to see if that would change the outcome of my label, but no.

Comment: sorry, typo there. should be a . instead of , and also the name of the equation should be the same. Making correction now.

Comment: I tested your code.  But, it gives an error `Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<fc><be><8d><b6><88><bc> 10^02'`

Comment: Hmmm I just tested the updated code block after restarting R, I do not get the same error (without loading any other packages than the ones in the question), but sometimes the \xB7 floating point seems to give problems. You can try to remove that from the function sci_form10()

Comment: Though I can't test it, an option is `bquote(atop(`

Comment: I removed the problematic symbol in the question code Akrun. Perhaps it works now.

Comment: Doess this work `plot(1, main = bquote(atop(.(gsub("\\.", "\\ ", parname))~"(a.u.)"~phantom(), "(" ~ mu~ " = "~ .(sci_form10(xmean))~ ", "~ sigma~ " = "~ .(sci_form10(xsigma))~ ")")))`

Comment: Can you check the solution I posted below.  I am using the new. `sci_form10`.  So the values would be differeent.  Otherwise, it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be wrap with `atop` to create line breaks

```
sci_form10 <- function(x) {
  paste(gsub("e\\+", " \u00B7 10^", scientific_format()(x)))
    }

x1 <-  sci_form10(xmean)
x2 <-  sci_form10(xsigma)
lst1 <- strsplit(c(x1,x2), "\\s(?=10)", perl = TRUE)
pre <- sapply(lst1, `[`, 1)
post <- sapply(lst1, `[`, 2)  
xmean1 <- parse(text = paste0("'", pre[1], "'"))[[1]]
xsigma1 <- parse(text = paste0("'", pre[2], "'"))[[1]]
post1 <- parse(text = post[1])[[1]]
post2 <- parse(text = post[2])[[1]]
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=cyl)) +
                  geom_point() +  
                    labs( x = bquote(atop(.(gsub("\\.", "\\ ", 
                      parname))~"(a.u.)"~phantom(), "(" ~ mu~ " = "~ .(xmean1) ~ .(post1) ~ ", " ~ sigma ~ " = " ~ .(xsigma1) ~ .(post2)~ ")")))
```

-output

[image]

Comment: looks good. I will try to figure out how to also get the actual values of mu and sigma into this line

Comment: @Mark  I think it should work on your side wiht the actual  function.  For me,  it is ssome issue with the encoding

Comment: no it turns for instance 8451 into 8.451^3 (where ^ indicated superscript)

Comment: @Mark If you check the output now, it is pretty much similar to the expected output you showed

Comment: my R studio is breaking it's neck again over \u00B7. Running it outside of R shiny, it produces Â instead of mid point. Even after changing the saving encoding to UTF-8

Comment: I changed it to a * for now and it works great! Thanks for the help Akrun

Comment: One last follow up question. Would there be a way to get rid of the left value and the comma (before the sigma symbol) somehow?

Comment: DId you meant the `mu = 1.23 * 10^2 , `

Comment: yes, or the 105.79 , when the nr is smaller than 1000 (I added a condition to the exp. format)

Comment: @Mark. Sorry, I didn't get the question correctly.  Can you post as a new question if it needs some major changes

Comment: No it's only a minor thing. Just how to remove the space before the comma in bquote

Comment: @Mark Ok, that would be just `labs( x = bquote(atop(.(gsub("\\.", "\\ ", 
                      parname))~"(a.u.)"~phantom(), "(" ~ mu~ " = "~ .(xmean1) ~ .(post1)*", " ~ sigma ~ " = " ~ .(xsigma1) ~ .(post2)~ ")")))`

Comment: Ah, the * instead of ~. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have something that does most of what you wanted.

```
changeSciNot <- function(n) {
  output <- format(n, digits=3, scientific = TRUE) # Transforms the number into scientific notation even if small
  output <- sub("e", "*10^", output) # Replace e with 10^
  output <- sub("\\+0?", "", output) # Remove + symbol and leading zeros on exponent, if > 1
  output <- sub("-0?", "-", output) # Leaves - symbol but removes leading zeros on exponent, if < 1
  output
}

# example data
parname <- "FL.Red.Total"
xmean <- 123.34
xsigma <- 2580.23
label <- bquote(atop(.(gsub("\\.", "\\ ", parname)) ~ "(a.u.)",
                     mu*"="*.(changeSciNot(xmean))*"," ~ sigma*"="*.(changeSciNot(xsigma))))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=cyl)) +
  geom_point() +  
  labs(x = label)
```

The `changeSciNot` function came from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785555/in-r-using-scientific-notation-10-rather-than-e). I had some problems using `\xB7` for the multiplication, so I left `*`. I also hard coded the number of digits for the format, but you can also make it into an argument. Hopefully, this will get you closer to the exact desired output.

Comment: I run into this error again with my shiny app that has the real plot in it when I use your approach: "Warning: Error in grid.Call.graphics: Metric information not available for this family/device"  Will test tomorrow what causes it