# Displaying scientific notation [papaja]

Tags: r, r-markdown, papaja

I have a large number in my code chunk:

```
a <-  1.234 * 10^36
```

Which I then print inline in my document:

```
What does this look like when knitted: `r a`
```

Knitting this in a standard .Rmd produces the expected **1.234 x 10^36**

But knitting in the papaja template produces the "computational format" with **1.234e+36**

Is there anyway to automate the formatting, without having to resort to a custom function like the  [solution given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785555/in-r-using-scientific-notation-10-rather-than-e)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable scientific notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-to-disable-scientific-notation)

Comment: No, that simply displays it without scientific notation. I'm looking to format the notation a particular way. It seems the default behaviour of papaja is different to the standard .Rmd template.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function `papaja::apa_num()`:

```r
> papaja::apa_num(1.234 * 10^36, format = "e")
[1] "$1.23 \\times 10^{36}$"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `knitr` to force formatting.

```
knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
  knitr:::format_sci(x, 'md')
})
```

This will format the appearance to look like this (having used your code as described above).

[image]

I wasn't fond of the uneven distribution of space about `x`, so I found captured the functions (and supporting functions) and was able to get:

[image]

For the former, I used as you indicated. This isn't what you would use for the second option, though.

```
`r a`
```

You wouldn't need to call the `hooks$set`, but you would need to call the modified function and encapsulate the call with `$`.

```
$`r format_sci(a)`$
```

Here are the slightly modified `knitr` functions that produced the second option:

````
```{r doAsISay}

# scientific notation in TeX, HTML and reST
format_sci_one = function(
  x, format = 'latex', times = getOption('knitr.inline.times', '\\times ')
) {

  if (!(class(x)[1] == 'numeric') || is.na(x) || x == 0) return(as.character(x))

  if (is.infinite(x)) {
    return(
      switch(format, latex = {
        sprintf("%s\\infty{}", ifelse(x < 0, "-", ""))
      }, html = {
        sprintf("%s&infin;", ifelse(x < 0, "-", ""))
      }, as.character(x)))
  }

  if (abs(lx <- floor(log10(abs(x)))) < getOption('scipen') + 4L)
    return(round_digits(x)) # no need sci notation

  b = round_digits(x / 10^lx)
  b[b %in% c(1, -1)] = ''

  switch(format, latex = {
    sci_notation('%s%s10^{%s}', b, times, lx)
  },
  html = sci_notation('%s%s10<sup>%s</sup>', b, ' &times; ', lx),
  md   = sci_notation('%s%s10^%s^', b, '&times; ', lx),
  rst  = {
    # if AsIs, use the :math: directive
    if (inherits(x, 'AsIs')) {
      s = sci_notation('%s%s10^{%s}', b, times, lx)
      sprintf(':math:`%s`', s)
    } else {
      # This needs the following line at the top of the file to define |times|
      # .. include <isonum.txt>
      sci_notation('%s%s10 :sup:`%s`', b, ' |times| ', lx)
    }
  }, as.character(x))
}

# vectorized version of format_sci_one()
format_sci = function(x, ...) {
  if (inherits(x, 'roman')) return(as.character(x))
  vapply(x, format_sci_one, character(1L), ..., USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}

sci_notation = function(format, base, times, power) {
  sprintf(format, base, ifelse(base == '', '', times), power)
}

round_digits = function(x) {
  if (getOption('knitr.digits.signif', FALSE)) format(x) else {
    as.character(round(x, getOption('digits')))
  }
}
```
````

Alternatively, you can change this in your download of the *knitr package*. (I've made modifications to my downloaded packages before, not `knitr`, though.)

FYI, this was tested with and the images were from the knitted RMD using the output set to `output: papaja::apa6_pdf`.